# Keep allowed_client_ids secret?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am developing an endpoint using Google App Engine's endpoint service.  I want to use authentication/authorization so only my javascript frontend can connect to it and users can only get their content.  I see from the endpoint docs, this can be accomplished by  setting the `allowed_client_ids` "field" in the Api decorator. However, I am using guthub to share/sync my code.  Is it ok to hard code the client_id in my file? If not, how can I keep it a secret but available to Google App Engine?

Comment: unfortunately, the only way to do that would be to keep the files containing sensitive data away from github. There are ways you could do a safe authentication on the server side and share that, but on the client whatever you place people can replicate.

Comment: How would I do it on the server side? I imagine that I will do the client development on my local machine or private repo...

Comment: What I meant is that there are auth methods like [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) which implementation can be shared because they don't provide any App specific info or sensitive data. Everything is handled under the covers by GAE. As your client code is living outside the GAE realm anything you can so someone can copy, you'll have to keep some code for yourself

Comment: Instead of hardcoding client secrets have your app read from a 'client_secrets.json' [1] file and add this to your .gitignore or keep it out of your source tree (ie. treat is as data, not code). You'll need to provide this file only when you actually deploy your app. [1] https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets